# I am trying to replace a string in a file via shell script where a part of the string is unknown

Tags: linux, string, shell, replace, sed

I have tried a few ways with sed as below without success:

```
sudo sed -i 's/(device.value=).*( )/\1 90 \2/g' /boot/cmdline.txt
sudo sed -i 's/device.value=.* /device.value=90/g' /boot/cmdline.txt
```

I do not know the value behind "=" which can have up to 2 digits.
Before and after the string there is a space, and the string always starts with "device.value="

PS: The file is a one liner with many values seperated through a space.

I would appreciate any help. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer:

```
sudo sed -i 's/device.value=.*/device.value=90/g' /boot/cmdline.txt
```